# Kafka partitions order of consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets assume that i have a single consumer and a topic with 2 partitions A and B

If the consumer is connected to both of these partitions, in which order will the messages be consumed?

e.g

```
Partition A

-------------
| A | B | C |
-------------

Partition B

-------------
| X | Y | Z |
-------------
```

Will the messages be consumed randomly e.g

```
A -> X -> Y -> B
```

Or is there any mechanisms (round-robin) that is applied

```
A -> X -> B -> Y -> C -> Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Kafka guarantees the order of messages only within a single partition.

The simplest way (not the most efficient one, though) to deal with this, is to create a single partition and run a single consumer.

Alternatively, you can partition the messages based on their key. Messages with the same key are inserted to the same partition and therefore the order of messages with the same key is guaranteed. For example, let's say that your data stream contains users' details. You can use e.g. `userID` as key, so that all of the messages for a user with a particular `userID` are inserted to the same partition. The consumer will then consume the messages of the user with `key=userID` in the exact order they have been inserted to the topic (or the partition to be more precise).

Comment: Yes, all that you mentioned im familiar with. More specifically what i was interested in was, Lets expand the example to 3 partitions. A B and C.  Once it has consumed X number of messages from partition A, will the next message consumed be from partition B or partition C. is it random which partitions are consumed next, or can it be made deterministic?

Comment: @dunnless You might read the messages in the order A, B, C or B, A, C or C, A, B or C, B, A. I am afraid you can not control the order;